# Yocto and Bazel

Tags: yocto, bazel

I am trying to (cross-)compile Bazel 0.4.5 in the Yocto system. The target is an ARMv7 and the Linux distro is Poky.

I am getting this compilation error:

```
| �  Building Bazel with Bazel.
| ................................
| ____Loading package: src
| ____Loading package: @bazel_tools//tools/cpp
| ____Loading package: @local_config_xcode//
| ERROR: in target '//external:cc_toolchain': no such package '@local_config_cc//': Traceback (most recent call last):
|       File "/home/giuseppe/.cache/bazel/_bazel_giuseppe/32d64188b76850bf1edfd4141b911134/external/bazel_tools/tools/cpp/cc_configure.bzl", line 584
|               _find_cc(repository_ctx)
|       File "/home/giuseppe/.cache/bazel/_bazel_giuseppe/32d64188b76850bf1edfd4141b911134/external/bazel_tools/tools/cpp/cc_configure.bzl", line 383, in _find_cc
|               repository_ctx.which(cc_name)
| Program argument of which() may not contains a / or a \ ('arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc  -march=armv7-a -marm -mfpu=neon  -mfloat-abi=hard -mcpu=cortex-a9 --sysroot=/home/giuseppe/research/projects/zynq/yocto/build/tmp/sysroots/zc702-zynq7' given).
| ____Elapsed time: 3.851s
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: I couldn't find a yocto recipe for bazel. If you wrote it on your own please give us a chance whether there is an error

Comment: For the record, this question was also asked on bazel-discuss mailing list and Brian gave it some thought: https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/bazel-discuss/TmBDKmoEvlI/GXng74b_AAAJ

Please provide us with more information like minimal failing example, the command you're running, what changes have you made to Bazel (if any), what changes have you made to the crosstool (if any), etc.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can take a look at the meta-tensorflow layer. Link:
    http://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/branch/master/layer/meta-tensorflow/

Comment: This just provides a link to an answer.

Comment: @RalfFriedl No it doesn't, it provides a layer which includes a recipe to Bazel. Do you even know yocto? This is a legit answer. For the user, they can take that layer, add it, then add bazel to their IMAGE_INSTALL and it should get pulled in.